# how to scroll down in another frame in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have to scroll down to load some contents in selenium  IDE. But It's not in the current window. It's subframe. How do I do that?. I know this command works with current window.

```
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().scrollTo(200,200)</td>
<td></td>
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate that has been answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488359/how-to-automate-mouse-scrolling-event-in-selenium-ide Try there, should give you what you need

Answer (score 0):

Select the required frame using `selectFrame(locator)` command, here locator is an element locator identifying a frame or iframe. Then try to execute your scroll command.